# Poner 2 valores en un DataTextField en un checkboxList

Tags: c#

mi problema es el siguiente quería saber si puedo poner 2 valores en mi checkboxList? 
ya que necesito que me aparezca el código de cuenta con el nombre de la cuenta

dejo mi codigo

Desde ya muchas gracias

```
        DataTable dtCuentas = null;


        string strConsulta = " exec SP_TABLA1_Mostrar_CuentasPertenecienteAClientes";

        if (aux == 1)
        {
            strConsulta = strConsulta + ", @cliente = '" + Session["ClienteAnalizar"].ToString() + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            strConsulta = strConsulta + " @cliente = '" + Session["ClienteAnalizar"].ToString() + "'";
            aux = 1;
        }


        dtCuentas = Conexion.llenarGridFromConsulta(strConsulta);

        chkCuentas2.Items.Clear();

        chkCuentas2.DataTextField = "CuentaDescripcion";            

        chkCuentas2.DataValueField = "CodigoCuenta";

        chkCuentas2.DataSource = dtCuentas;

        chkCuentas2.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que voy a mencionar es que no se ejecuta un procedure de esa forma, no se que haces en `llenarGridFromConsulta()` pero sino permites parametros esta mal.

Tu codigo deberia ser como esto

```
string cliente = Session["ClienteAnalizar"].ToString();

DataTabla dtCuentas = new DataTable(); 
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")) 
{ 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_TABLA1_Mostrar_CuentasPertenecienteAClientes", conn); 
    cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure; 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cliente", cliente); 

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
    da.Fill(dtCuentas); 
}
```

- Se asigna el `CommandType` indicando que es un procedure, no se sa ningun `exec`
- Se usan siempre parametros, no se concatena nada en un string

Ahora bien para ver mas de un campo lo puedes resolver en la consulta

```
SELECT CodigoCuenta, '(' + CodigoCuenta + ')' + CuentaDescripcion As CuentaDescripcion FROM NombreTabla WHERE cliente = @cliente
```

asi unes mas de en campo en el SELECT y lo asignas al `DataTextField`